# XMLHttpRequest Breaking HTML code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

This appears to be an issue with grabbing this info, the following is parsed on my *.php file:

```
<form method="POST" action="portalofinfiniteawesome.php">
<input type="hidden" name="account" value="' . $username . '" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="wrong">These are wrong</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Nevermind</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="right">View Buddies</button>
</form>
```

However when I grab this with:

```
    function showHint(str)
    {
    if (str.length<4)
      {
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML="";
      return;
      }
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","searcher.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

Onto my new page, it is rendered as:

```
<form method="POST" action="portalofinfiniteawesome.php"></form>
<input type="hidden" name="account" value="' . $username . '" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="wrong">These are wrong</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Nevermind</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="right">View Buddies</button>
```

I just need this to work, I do not care if I need to use jquery or anything in addition, just hoping to resolve this issue and would appreciate getting an answer or at least being put in the right direction.

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Problem persists on IE, Firefox, Chrome

Comment: I don't get your problem. Between the first and the last example there's no difference.

Comment: where is results element???????

Comment: What browser are you using to test it?

Comment: The difference is the </form> is rendered on the same line as <form>.  Testing in Mozilla Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
<input type="hidden" name="account" value="' . $username . '" />
```

With this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="account" value="' . $username . '" ></input>
```

Firefox can do that.

Comment: Problem still persists

Answer (score 0):

My one pence:

Unless the form block is inside a PHP string, then the respective line should be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="account" value="<?php echo $username ?>" />
```